# GTLServiceDrive executeQuery in iOS generating unauthorized_client error

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to add Google's Drive service to my Objective-C app, but I'm receiving:

```
Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)"
<snip>
{
  error = "unauthorized_client";
}
```

when attempting a queryForFiles: immediately after I've successfully authenticated via:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch:initWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" clientID:GENERATED_ID_FROM_CONSOLE clientSecret:GENERATED_SECRET_FROM_CONSOLE keychainItemName:@"App Tag" delegate:self finishedSelector
```

When I created my project on the developers console, I chose "installed app" and "other" (not iOS), as I saw was the problem in several other posts.  And I've checked that the id and secret are indeed correct in my app.

Another post mentioned a possible correlation between Google's project id and the app's bundle ID; unfortunately, my app bundle ID is slightly different from my project id in the developer's console, as the developer's console doesn't allow uppercase letters. I'm hoping that this *not* the problem, as I don't want to have to change my bundle ID.

Any suggestions as to why my app is *unauthorized* would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can confirm the error is saying the client id in your code doesn't match the API Console. As well as checking they are a perfect character match, make sure you have enabled the Drive API and SDK in the console.

Comment: Argh!  I didn't have the Drive API enabled, just the SDK.  Let me check the code again, thanks.

Comment: Whoops, just read that I'm not supposed to say "Thanks".  My mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pinoyyid hinted, I did not have the drive API enabled (only the SDK).  Removing my credentials from the keychain, and re-authorizing solved my problem.